# How can I add a drop down button to a column item inside a table view - JavaFX

Tags: javafx, gluon, gluon-mobile

I know that's nothing new to add a drop down button to a column item inside a table view. But I want to do that, without creating a container class.

I have created this table view by using Scene Builder from Gluon.

[image]

To fill the left column, I have first created these fields.

```
@FXML
private TableView<String> tableView;

@FXML
private TableColumn<String, String> columnConfiguration;

private ObservableList<String> rowNames;

private String[] leftColumn = {"Seed", "Optimization algorithm", "Weight init", "Updater", "Learning rate", "Momentum", "Regularization", "Regularization coefficient"};
```

Then I have insert the text values by using this code

```
 columnConfiguration.setCellValueFactory(data -> new SimpleStringProperty(data.getValue()));
 rowNames = FXCollections.observableArrayList();
 tableView.setItems(rowNames);
 rowNames.addAll(leftColumn);
```

**Question:**

How can I insert [DropDownButton](https://docs.gluonhq.com/charm/javadoc/5.0.2/com/gluonhq/charm/glisten/control/DropdownButton.html)  to the right column, if I add a private field like this:

```
@FXML
private TableColumn<DropdownButton, String> columnValue;

private ObservableList<DropdownButton> dropDownButtons;
```

How can I include a drop down button object to the right column.

```
DropdownButton seeds = new DropdownButton();
seeds.getItems().add(new MenuItem("100"), new MenuItem("200")...);
```

I think it has to do with this line. But this is for strings, not drop down buttons. Do you know what to change so it will fit the DropdownButton class?

```
columnValue.setCellValueFactory(data -> new SimpleStringProperty(data.getValue()));
```

Comment: Don't mix model and view. You should have a model class (i.e. `Items`) that holds the strings fields of possible dropdown menu items, like `item1`, `item2`, ... Then your `TableColumn<Config, Items>` will use `setCellValueFactory` and `SimpleObjectProperty` to hold one model instance, and you will use `setCellFactory` to do the actual rendering with the type of controls you want, like a `DropdownButton`. But I strongly suggest a different approach, using [`SettingsPane`](https://docs.gluonhq.com/charm/javadoc/5.0.2/com/gluonhq/charm/glisten/control/SettingsPane.html).

Comment: @JoséPereda Ok! I have to do in that way. Thank you for your reply.